# Click event find next div to add a css class Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to make a function in Typescript to find the next div and add it a css class, here is my try:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle()">Item 1</a></li>
    <div class="content hide"></div>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle()">Item 2</a></li>
    <div class="content hide"></div>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle()">Item 3</a></li>
    <div class="content hide"></div>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle()">Item 4</a></li>
    <div class="content hide"></div>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle()">Item 5</a></li>
    <div class="content hide"></div>
</ul>
```

Now the function in Typescript

```
function toggle(){
   this.parent().next('.content').class('hide');
}
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Create a typescript function when you press onclick find the next .content and add a class .hide @gcampbell

Comment: `this` is not what you are assuming!

Answer (score 0):

> `this` is not what you are assuming! You are suppose to pass current element as `this` as argument.

Also note there is no `.class` method, you should be using `.toggleClass` method.

```js
function toggle(elem) {
  $(elem).parent().next('.content').toggleClass('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <div class="content hide">Content Goes here!</div>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <div class="content hide">Content Goes here!</div>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <div class="content hide">Content Goes here!</div>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)">Item 4</a>
  </li>
  <div class="content hide">Content Goes here!</div>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)">Item 5</a>
  </li>
  <div class="content hide">Content Goes here!</div>
</ul>
```

*But it is better to use `jQuery-event-binding` than `Inline-event-binding`*

```js
function toggle() {
  $(this).parent().next('.content').toggleClass('hide'); //this will refer to current element!
}
$('li a').on('click', toggle);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <div class="content hide">Content Goes here!</div>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle(this)">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <div class="content hide">Content Goes here!</div>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <div class="content hide">Content Goes here!</div>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
  </li>
  <div class="content hide">Content Goes here!</div>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
  </li>
  <div class="content hide">Content Goes here!</div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

```
<a (click)="showparent($event)" class="collapsible-header">show next element</a>
<div class="collapsible-body" style="display:none">
   <ul>
     <li>Node2</li>
     <li>Node2</li>
     <li>Node2</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

TypeScript Code

```
showparent(elem){
    const target = elem
    const display = target.toElement.nextSibling.style.display

    if(display == 'block'){
      target.toElement.nextSibling.style.display = 'none'
    }else{
      target.toElement.nextSibling.style.display = 'block'
    }
  }
```